# IE 11 Expands Content Horizontally On Load

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile & am stuck...  In **IE 11**, when clicking on any of the pages in this site, the content loads & then expands horizontally to where it is supposed to be.  I don't even know how to explain this...  I have never seen this behavior before.  The site is [gramercy-consulting.centnerconsulting.com](http://gramercy-consulting.centnerconsulting.com).  It doesn't happen every time, but almost every time.  I've also noticed that if I have the Developer Tools open, it doesn't happen.  Any ideas how to fix this?  I have tried commenting out custom css that impacts the width, as well as messing with float/clear, but I didn't have any luck.  This does not happen in Chrome or FF.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I can't understand the question you're asking.  Please consider being more specific, and possibly including screenshots.

Comment: Hi, John.  Sorry, it doesn't show in a screen shot, it would have to be a video.  When you click on the pages, the text moves for a second or two until it fills the container.  I really don't know how else to explain it, or even what code to look at to post here.  I assume it has something to do with the container element, but I'm really not sure.  If you can view the site in IE 11, just click on a few of the pages & you'll see what I mean.  I wish I could be more specific....  But, ultimately, I want the text to render on the page without this expanding effect that it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow-up to close this out...  I finally figured out the issue.  There was a transition property applied to the inner-wrapper that I didn't see before.  Once I cleared that with:

```
#inner-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

the problem was resolved.  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the website in IE9, IE11 and in google chrome, i dont see any issues it loads the same as when using it in chrome. Clear your cache and try again if not post the video so we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks for looking!  It does not happen in Chrome, only in IE11.  I cleared cache in IE & still see the issue.  Here is a link to a video of what I see:  http://youtu.be/BEKf1uMChY8   Please note that the URL is different, but the files are the same & have the same behavior.

Comment: It has to do with the width of the site. is a wordpress website or did you create it in dreamweaver?

Comment: It is a WordPress site, utilizing WooThemes Canvas that is customized with a child theme (I use these frequently).  Could it have to do with the box-shadow, or is it the container elements within?  Thanks!